# How to use GDAL on Heroku?

Tags: python, gdal, heroku

I have a geospatial python app that I want to use on Heroku.

This is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.19
Werkzeug==0.9.4
gunicorn==18.0
itsdangerous==0.23
numpy==1.8.0
requests==2.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I want to use the [heroku-buildpack-geodjango](http://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango/) to install Python GDAL.
I create and do a git push.

```
heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack http://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango/

git push heroku master
```

This all works fine. However the app crashes because it doesn't find GDAL.

These are my logs:

```
$ heroku logs
...
2014-03-23T18:57:08.224720+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named osgeo
2014-03-23T18:57:08.348803+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-03-23 18:57:08 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-03-23T18:57:08.348803+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-03-23 18:57:08 [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
...
```

How do I set up GDAL in order to work properly?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Heroku support? I don't know if GDAL is something they have installed on their platform but they could probably help you figure it out.

Comment: Does it matter that the build pack is for django and you are using flask?

Answer (score 1):

You can [add a build pack](https://help.heroku.com/Q0VCG3DE/how-do-i-install-gdal-on-heroku) following these directions from heroku.